# Unexpected token when use Public keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, apollo

As per Apollo Documentation adding Custom Directive is as follow:

```
class isAuth extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
    // field defination for resolving
    // directive.
    public visitFieldDefinition(field) {
        // overspreading.
        const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;

        // resolve field.
        field.resolve = async function(__, Context) {
            // check if Context
            // contain's user object
            // which was resolved by jwt.
            if(!Context.user){
                throw new Error('User not authenticated');
            }

            // resolve return awaited resolve call.
            return await resolve.apply(this, __);
        };
    }
}
```

but using this will going to result in an unexpected token error.

```
class isAuth extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
    // field defination for resolving
    // directive.
    visitFieldDefinition(field) { <---- Removed Public keyword
        // overspreading.
        const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;

        // resolve field.
        field.resolve = async function(__, Context) {
            // check if Context
            // contain's user object
            // which was resolved by jwt.
            if(!Context.user){
                throw new Error('User not authenticated');
            }

            // resolve return awaited resolve call.
            return await resolve.apply(this, __);
        };
    }
}
```

this will going to work but not for apollo Package.

please note: Apollo is graphql library

Answer (score 2):

`public` keyword is present in JavaScript but it is [reserved for future use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords).

Therefore as of 2019, any JavaScript parser will always give you unexpected token error.

Comment: Typescript support it though.